# backend code not working to push id to friends property array

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

When the "Follow user" button is clicked (in Frienddetail component) the addPeopleFollow function is invoked. With this function I want to store the id of the user clicked (the one you are trying to follow) in the friends Array property of the user that is logged in/clicked on my database.

My database has a user collection with all users in with per user this:

```
_id:5eff397b70d78284c8c45186
friends:Array
username:"charlestryingout"
password:"$2b$10$CYMyPx10gk0jO5XoazcrSO32Ng37qoyU6uXkkeaswQ5KWm7k7ooym"
__v:0
```

For example: if user with id = 5eff397b70d78284c8c45186 clicks the other user to follow with id = 5eff397b70d78284c8c45187, then I would want to have this as a result in my database:

```
_id:5eff397b70d78284c8c45186
friends:Array[5eff397b70d78284c8c45187]
username:"charlestryingout"
password:"$2b$10$CYMyPx10gk0jO5XoazcrSO32Ng37qoyU6uXkkeaswQ5KWm7k7ooym"
__v:0
```

I have coded the content of the addPeopleFollow function (axios request) and managed to get it working (I can see the console.logs in the .then in my console). Feel free to suggest changes if you think it is incomplete.

**My question:**
Can someone help me writing the backend (first version below)?

Could you please write out the full code (think just backend but feel free to suggest changes in frontend as well. I am using Node/Mongoose/MongoDB/React

---

**Front-end**

```
addPeopleFollow(idpeopleyoufollow){
    Axios({
        method: "POST",
        url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE}/friends`,
        data: qs.stringify(idpeopleyoufollow),
        headers: {"content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
        withCredentials: true
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log("charles")
        console.log(idpeopleyoufollow)
        console.log("charles")
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.response)
    })
}

render() {
    return (
        <DefaultLayout>
        <div className="friendsoverviewcontainer">
            <h1>Our community ({this.state.friends.length} registered users)</h1>
            <form className="friends">               
                <div className="titlepart">
                    <label className="friendlabel" htmlFor="friend">Search for Users :</label><br></br>
                    <input className="friendform" type="text" name="friend" value={this.state.friend} placeholder="Type a username here!" onChange={this.searchFriends}></input>
                </div>
            </form>

            <div className="friendsboxes" >
                {
                    this.state.searchFriends.map(friend =>
                        <div key={friend._id}>
                            <Frienddetail 
                                key={friend._id}
                                id={friend._id}
                                username={friend.username}
                                location={friend.location}
                                innerCircle={this.addToInnerCircle}
                                peopleFollow={this.addPeopleFollow}
                            />
                        </div>
                    )   
                }
            </div>
        </div>
```

---

**Frienddetail component**

```
import React from 'react'
import './Frienddetail.css'

class Frienddetail extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()

        this.state = {
            
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
                <div className="friendbox">
                    <img className="imagedaredevilspicdetail" src="/images/profileimage.png" alt="picturesetting" />
                    <p className="friend">{this.props.username}</p>
                    <p className="friend">{this.props.location}</p>
                    <button className="followbutton" onClick={(e) => this.props.peopleFollow(this.props.id)}>Follow user!</button>
                    <button className="friendbutton" onClick={(e)=> this.props.innerCircle(this.props.id)}>Add to inner circle!</button>
                </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Frienddetail
```

---

**Backend**

```
// add peopleYouFollow
router.post("/friends", (req,res) => {
  console.log("thisishappening")
  let iduser = getUser()._id 
  console.log(iduser)
  User
  .findByIdAndUpdate({_id:iduser},{$push:{friends:req.body._id}})
  .then((response) => {
    res.json(response)
    console.log("thisishappening")
  })
  .catch(error => {
    res.json(error)
  })
})
```

---

**Usermodel**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    location: String,
    imageUrl: String,
    friends: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],
    error: String
})

const User = mongoose.model("users",userSchema)

module.exports = User;
```

Answer (score 0):

there are some breaking changes I would do, if I was going to implement the follow route these are just my opinion so I would assume you have body-parser. so in your frontend, you would send a form POST request to /follow to the server/backend with information in JSON like {following: 1242424}

plus i am not sure about your 'getUser().id'

I would do something like this.

**Backend**

```
// add peopleYouFollow
router.post("/follow/:id", async (req,res, next) => {
try{
  {following} = req.body;
let user = await User.findById(req.params.id);

if (!user) {
    return next(err);
}
  const updatedUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,{$push:{friends:following}}, {new:true, runValidators:true})

res.json({success:true,data:updatedUser})

}catch(err){
//handle error
next(err)
}
  
})
```

TIP:
-> use AsyncHandler // google it up
-> use async/await for cleaner code ... promises are fine but may get a bit complicated
-> remove the password for MongoDB selected for security reasons
-> handle error efficiently